# What references does Visual Studio add when I accidentally click Add New Winform?

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, reference

Strangely enough, this is not on The Google.  And I could really use a list so I know which ones I need to remove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just ran a little experiment (cleared references, added a winform), and it adds:

- System
- System.Data
- System.Drawing
- System.Windows.Forms
- System.Xml

Answer (score 2):

On the references screen, there is an Unused References button.  This will show you what reference are not being used and gives you the choice to remove them.  This works 95% of the time.  Every so often, if there is a shared library in there, it will tell you it isn't being used but it really is.

This is useful for problems like this, not just Windows Forms.

Comment: If you go to your project properties in VS, there is a references tab.  Clicking on that tab displays the list of references being used by your application.  On that same screen, you will find the Unused References button.  This is the procedure for VB.NET.  I can't remember if it is the same for C#.  The screens may look slightly different.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much it will make sure that the following are added.

- System.Windows.Forms
- System.Drawing

It may also try to add System.Data and System.Xml but those are defaults on most project types so it's hard to tell.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not trolling for votes really, so much as I'm surprised that there is no answer to this on google